# Having some issues with python XML parsing

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm new to parsing xml files with Python.  Could I get a little help on this one, if you dont mind.

Here is a snippet of my xml doc:

```
<xxxxx>

  <xxxx name="xxxxx">
    <xxxxx value="xxxxx"/>
    <xxxxx value="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>

    <xxxx>

      <xxxxx>
        <xxxx value="ReadWrite"/>
        <Type value="XXXXX"/>
      </xxxxx>
```

I just need to get the User name field. through out the file.

Here is my code that I have been working on:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xmlD = etree.parse("c:/Python27/doc.xml")
root = xmld.getroot()

for child in root:
    for children in child:
        print (children.txt)
        print("\n")
```

I'm not a expert, just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could get that information.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your `root` element, you can find all your `<User>` elements using the XPath selector `'.//User'` ("select all `User` elements found anywhere beneath the current element"), and then loop over them and get their `name` attributes.

```
>>> [user.get('name') for user in root.findall('.//User')]
['admin']
```